# Why doesn't the 'ComputerMove' subroutine get executed?

Tags: c#

I am trying to program a game called NIM (https://plus.maths.org/content/play-win-nim). The subroutine 'ComputerMove();' does not execute for some reason, why is that? I am yet to finish but it is the ComputerMove subroutine that I am confused with. Apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious.
(Edit: There is no error message, just a blank console)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace THE_NIM
{
    class Program
    {
        static char[,] Board = new char[7, 12];
        static string underline = "\x1B[4m";
        static string reset = "\x1B[0m";
        static bool GameStatus = false;
        static string firstMove;
        static void Introduction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t" + underline + "Welcome to NIM!\n" + reset);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(underline + "The rules are as follows:\n" + reset);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("   - Each player takes their turn to remove a certain number of 'blocks' from a stack, of which there are 7.");
            Console.WriteLine("   - This happens until there is only 1 'block' remaining. With the winner being the one to remove the last 'block'.\n");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }
        static void PrintBoard()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("   ");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 11; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(Board[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    static void WhoGoesFirst()
    {
        string[] PossibleChoices = { "Computer", "You" };

        Random WhoGoesFirst = new Random();
        int WGFIndex = WhoGoesFirst.Next(0, 2);

        firstMove = PossibleChoices[WGFIndex];

        Console.WriteLine("Randomly selecting who goes first...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} will go first!\n", firstMove);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    static void PlayerMove()
    {
        Console.Write("Which stack do you wish to remove from?: ");
        int PlayerStackSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (PlayerStackSelection)
        {
            case(1):
                PlayerStackSelection = 0;
                break;
            case (2):
                PlayerStackSelection = 2;
                break;
            case (3):
                PlayerStackSelection = 4;
                break;
            case (4):
                PlayerStackSelection = 6;
                break;
            case (5):
                PlayerStackSelection = 8;
                break;
            case (6):
                PlayerStackSelection = 10;
                break;
        }

        Console.Write("How many blocks do you wish to remove?: ");
        int PlayerRemovedSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int spaces = 0;
        int nearestBlock = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (Board[i, PlayerStackSelection] == ' ')
            {
                spaces += 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (Board[i, PlayerStackSelection] == '█')
            {
                nearestBlock = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (spaces != 7)
        {
            for (int i = nearestBlock; i < (nearestBlock + PlayerRemovedSelection); i++)
            {
                Board[i, PlayerStackSelection] = ' ';
            }
        }

        PrintBoard();
        CheckIfBoardEmpty();
    }
    static void ComputerMove()
    {
        Random CompStack = new Random();
        int CompStackSelection = CompStack.Next(1, 7);
        int PreChangeStack = CompStackSelection;

        switch (CompStackSelection)
        {
            case (1):
                CompStackSelection = 0;
                break;
            case (2):
                CompStackSelection = 2;
                break;
            case (3):
                CompStackSelection = 4;
                break;
            case (4):
                CompStackSelection = 6;
                break;
            case (5):
                CompStackSelection = 8;
                break;
            case (6):
                CompStackSelection = 10;
                break;
        }

        Random CompRemoved = new Random();
        int CompRemovedSelection = CompRemoved.Next(1, 7);

        int spaces = 0;
        int nearestBlock = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (Board[i, CompStackSelection] == ' ')
            {
                spaces += 1;
            }
        }

        while (spaces == 7)
        {
            CompRemovedSelection = CompRemoved.Next(1, 7);
            CompStackSelection = CompStack.Next(1, 7);

            switch (CompStackSelection)
            {
                case (1):
                    CompStackSelection = 0;
                    break;
                case (2):
                    CompStackSelection = 2;
                    break;
                case (3):
                    CompStackSelection = 4;
                    break;
                case (4):
                    CompStackSelection = 6;
                    break;
                case (5):
                    CompStackSelection = 8;
                    break;
                case (6):
                    CompStackSelection = 10;
                    break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                if (Board[i, CompStackSelection] == ' ')
                {
                    spaces += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (Board[i, CompStackSelection] == '█')
            {
                nearestBlock = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ((nearestBlock + CompRemovedSelection) !< 8)
        {
            while ((nearestBlock + CompRemovedSelection) !< 8)
            {
                CompRemovedSelection = CompRemoved.Next(1, 7);
            }
        }

        if (spaces != 7)
        {
            for (int i = nearestBlock; i < (nearestBlock + CompRemovedSelection); i++)
            {
                Board[i, CompStackSelection] = ' ';
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Computer is making its move... ");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Computer has decided to remove {0} blocks from stack number {1}.\n", CompRemovedSelection, PreChangeStack);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        PrintBoard();
        CheckIfBoardEmpty();
    }
    static void CheckIfBoardEmpty()
    {
        bool keepGoing = false;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 11; j++)
            {
                if (Board[i,j] == '█')
                {
                    GameStatus = false;
                    keepGoing = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (keepGoing != true)
        {
            Console.Write("BOARD EMPTY");
            GameStatus = true;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Introduction();
        WhoGoesFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 11; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Board[i, j] = '█';
                }
                else
                {
                    Board[i, j] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }

        if (firstMove == "You")
        {
            while (GameStatus == false)
            {
                PlayerMove();
                ComputerMove();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (GameStatus == false)
            {
                ComputerMove();
                PlayerMove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, just a blank console when it tries to execute ComputerMove

Comment: @Somebody This sounds like a perfect opportunity to put a breakpoint in your `ComputerMove` function and step through your code manually and see what's happening. Have you tried using the debugger to see what's going on when this function gets called?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: You have to set a breakpoint and debug the program.

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Put a break point on "GameStatus = true;" and see if GameStatus is getting set to true.  It is the only way that ComputerMove will not be called.